# How to identify a word that starts with a number or special character not using regex?

Tags: python, string, numbers, special-characters

I need to remove words from a string that begin with a number or special character. I cannot simply put specific values since the string is based on user input, so it will be unknown. All I've been able to come up with, without having to import anything, is using

`` .startswith(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~', ')', ':') ``

There must be an easier, less lengthy way, right?

Comment: @rv.kvetch they said they can't import anything...

Comment: ah, apparently didnt' read that part. my bad.

Comment: Is there a reason why `if not mystring[0].isalpha()` would not solve the problem?

Comment: Well. I feel silly now for not even thinking of that simple approach.

Comment: We all have blind spots sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to remove words from a string that begin with a number or special character. [...]

I'd suggest taking a look at the `string` module. This is a builtin module which defines common characters such as punctuation, digits, alphanumeric characters, etc.

From there, it should be straightforward enough to transfer the desired variables from the `string` module as variables that you define in code:

```
digits = '0123456789'
punctuation = r"""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""

invalid_start_chars = digits + punctuation
```

Then test with a sample input:

```
string = "Hello 123World H0w's @It [Going? Testing123"

print(' '.join(
    [word for word in string.split()
     if word[0] not in invalid_start_chars]
))
```

Output:

```
Hello H0w's Testing123
```

Comment: The question says *without having to import anything*. Your suggestion involves doing `import string`, no?

Comment: I can clarify, but my suggestion was to copy those variables defined in `string` into the own module namespace

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use standart module `string`.

```py
from string import punctuation


def check_word(word: str) -> bool:
    return not word.startswith(tuple(punctuation+'0123456789'))


def fix_string(s: str) -> str:
    return " ".join(word for word in s.split() if check_word(word))
```

So you could use function `fix_string` like this:

```py
s = "Hello !world! This is a good .test"
print('Result:', fix_string(s))
# Result: Hello This is a good
```